# VBA Access datatype mismatch

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting a data type mismatch error with the following code in my access database.

```
If IsNull(NewZipBox) = False Then
DoCmd.RunSQL ("UPDATE ShipAddressTest SET Zip = NewZipBox WHERE [ShipAddressTest.Zip]= '" &      Me.List90.Column(5) & "';")
End If
```

I have the field Zip set to a number data type. When I change it to text this error goes away. Could anyone explain why I am getting this error and what I might be able to do about it?

I'll provide any other information that you need.

Comment: Remove the `'` single quotes if the column is not a string type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NewZipBox input is string data (text) so if you are assigning that to a variable declared as a numeric (integer?) data type, that is why the mismatch error occurs. You could use the CInt() function to convert your input text before assigning it to Zip.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I use CInt(Me.NewZipBox) I get an overflow error. What is the proper way to use CInt with a textbox?

Comment: I could have been clearer, Alec. I apologize. I wasn't really sure what numeric data type you had declared your zip field as and just chose Int, since it uses the least amount of memory. I'm so used to .net that I forgot Int is only 16 bits in VB and VBA, so the max value you can use is 32767. Any zip where the value is greater than 32767 will cause an overflow error. If you declared Zip as a Long, use the conversion function CLng() on your input text and it should work for you. Definitely should not get an overflow error.